# Amend PHP Object properties on the fly

Tags: php, oop, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP how can I access a “:private” array in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286798/in-php-how-can-i-access-a-private-array-in-an-object)

I am not sure if there is a right way to do this or if this is completely unacceptable technique.
I am using PHP and I am in a situation where a script is given an object, it does not have access to the objects Class and many of the properties are protected (see below).
Is it possible to "hack" (bad choice of words) the object manually to amend property values on the fly? 
Not sure of a way to do this or if there is a way by converting one way and then back again.

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#3 (16) {


["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(28) "Zend_Controller_Request_Http"
  ["_paramSources":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "_GET"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "_POST"
  }
  ["_requestUri":protected]=>
  string(13) "/?mod=mainnav"
  ["_baseUrl":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_basePath":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_pathInfo":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["_params":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_rawBody":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_aliases":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_dispatched":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_module":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_moduleKey":protected]=>
  string(6) "module"
  ["_controller":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_controllerKey":protected]=>
  string(10) "controller"
  ["_action":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_actionKey":protected]=>
  string(6) "action"
}
```

Comment: cant you change the object's class instead? Or extend it?

Comment: So, you want to modify the `protected` properties of the object?

Comment: If there is a way to convert the objects class, fix the protected property and then change the objects name back. The entire thing is serialized and md5 encoded at the end so it would have to match one from a Zend Framework application. Might be impossible without having access to the required Zend Framework.

Comment: Well, Zend Framework is Open Source and freely available and it's likely installed on your webserver where the error occurs, so you should have access to it. But if this stems from an unserialized file, then the culprit is likely that the class changed over time and you unserialized an old string. In that case, you just want to throw it away. Can you give more details please. Where does the file come from? A Cache?

Comment: Thanks, seems 'Reflections' are the way to go.

Comment: Are you sure there are no built in methods that are purposely created to change those protected properties?

Comment: There are methods inside Zend Framework to do so, but without access to the framework I can not call those methods. It it easy to do the above if you have access to the 'Zend_Controller_Request_Http' class..unfortunately I do not. 
It is done with `$request->setRequestUri($url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using a more simple technique to do this.
I have the Object serialized into a string. So I simply replaced the current value (which I always have) with the new value using preg_replace.
There is some regex which will find the variable name and then I could change its value (so doesn't require knowing the value) but I hadn't been able to complete that yet (and I do have the current value).

```
$objectA = serialize($request);
$current_url = '\?mod=mainnav';
$new_url = 'newpage';
$objectB = preg_replace('/'.$current_url.'/', $new_url, $objectA);

//check the new object
var_dump('<pre>');
var_dump(unserialize($objectB));
var_dump('</pre>');
```

Using Reflections is probably the better technique most of the time, but for what I needed here I felt this was an simple and fast way to do it plus keeps all other object properties.

Answer (score 1):

If properties are protected you can create a class that extends from this one and modify any properties. If they are private look at Reflection:

```
$reflecRequest = new ReflectionObject($request);
$reflecRequestProp = $reflecRequest->getProperty('_requestUri');
$reflecRequestProp->setAccessible(true);
$reflecRequestProp->setValue($request, 'newUri');
```

Comment: I dont have access from here to the Classes library. I am afraid it must be done on the fly and using the Object as it is at that moment. I am trying with a PHP Reflection object but I am not sure I will be able to produce an exact replica of what is printed above (but with a different param value)

Comment: currently I have `$request = $object;

 $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Zend_Controller_Request_Http');

 $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('_requestUri');

 $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);

 $reflectionClass->getProperty('_requestUri')->setValue('newUri');`

Comment: Try this
$reflecRequest = new ReflectionObject($request);
$reflecRequestProp = $reflecRequest->getProperty('_requestUri');
$reflecRequestProp->setAccessible(true);
$reflecRequestProp->setValue('newUri');

Comment: Thanks, that has the name (which is a big win) but none of the member properties. Hopefully a quick fix.

Comment: produces 'Warning: ReflectionProperty::setValue() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 give'
changed the last line to 
`$reflecRequestProp->setValue($reflecRequest, 'newUri');` and prints that property but none of the others, at least I can manually add the rest here. Thanks

Comment: sorry forgot the first parameter so now you can create a tool that will allow you to change any properties in any class.

Comment: no worries, just thankful you pointed me to the method which seems to be the most useful method for this. appreciated

Comment: don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Comment: yep, may do entire solution and post that as answer so its complete.