# paypal get phone number

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I'm using Paypal rest-api-sdk-php (this example) http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html

This is the payment execution:
https://i.gyazo.com/42e6b22951b7b82e7b6193d18cce6042.png

In their printed response object, I can see phone is already present there https://i.gyazo.com/b4b65b445a5696e42908a1514d3eb33c.png

but when I want to access $result->payer->payer_info->phone it doesn't return anything.

not even when I print_r the payment execution $result
https://i.gyazo.com/971926556ee9d7d46443a73616e36056.png

do you see anything I'm not noticing? can you please point me in the right direction? 
there must be something I'm not getting here. 
I've spent 1 hour with this.

Comment: nobody has any idea?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8287026/5701450) this way it will shorted because you are getting protected array

Comment: perhaps you need a permission for getting an access to phone number. Have you check with PayPal?