# How to get "variable" of Response Object

Tags: php, arrays, api, object, response

I'm using an API in PHP that when I call one function it prints:

```
PagSeguro\Parsers\Transaction\CreditCard\Response Object
(
    [date:PagSeguro\Parsers\Transaction\Response:private] => 2021-11-04T21:10:12.000-03:00
    [code:PagSeguro\Parsers\Transaction\Response:private] => X
    [reference:PagSeguro\Parsers\Transaction\Response:private] => Y

[...]
```

I need to get the `code:PagSeguro\Parsers\Transaction\Response:private` result but I didn't find out how. To call this response the line is:  `$result = $creditCard->register(\PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::getAccountCredentials());`

Comment: [how-can-i-access-a-private-array-in-an-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286798/in-php-how-can-i-access-a-private-array-in-an-object) might help

Comment: It returns ```Property code does not exist```, but I'm reading the ReflectionObject documentation tryin to find something that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that I did to make it work.

```
try {
    //Get the crendentials and register the boleto payment
    $result = $creditCard->register(
        \PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::getAccountCredentials()
    );
    
    $array = (array) $result; // makes it a "normal" array
    $values = array_values($array); // get all those values
    $transactionid = $values[1]; // returns the second value
```